# Passing C pointers by reference?

Tags: c, list, pointers, reference

I found some entries for passing pointers by reference, but didn't really understand them.

I have written this function to insert a node in a linked list. It seems to work within the function, but the changes of the `linkedList` pointer do not affect the pointer back in the main function. Is there an easy fix? In the classroom example, the `linkedList` pointer is declared globally, but I thought it would be preferable to pass it around, so I could make more than one linked list.

```
void insert(node* linkedList, int value)
{
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        // failed to make node
        printf("Failed to insert new node!\n");
        return;
    }

    newNode->n = value;

    printf("\n");
    printf("Before insert: \n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("linkedList ptr : %p\n", linkedList);
    printf("linkedList->n : %i\n", linkedList->n);
    printf("LinkedList->next : %p\n", linkedList->next);

    printf("\n");
    printf("newNode ptr : %p\n", newNode);
    printf("newNode->n : %i\n", newNode->n);
    printf("newNode->next : %p\n", newNode->next);

    newNode->next = linkedList;
    linkedList = newNode;

    printf("\n");
    printf("After insert: \n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("linkedList ptr : %p\n", linkedList);
    printf("linkedList->n : %i\n", linkedList->n);
    printf("LinkedList->next : %p\n", linkedList->next);

    printf("\n");
    printf("newNode ptr : %p\n", newNode);
    printf("newNode->n : %i\n", newNode->n);
    printf("newNode->next : %p\n", newNode->next);
}
```

Comment: Sure there's an easy fix - get rid of 'void insert' and return the head.

Comment: Or use a double pointer and update value using the reference.

Comment: I was going to suggest that too. Just returned the new linked list. Use like this: `list = insert( list, number )`

Comment: @Haris: To avoid confusion, I suggest not using the term "double pointer", which can refer to `double*`.

Comment: This is a standard problem in linked list code in C.  There are an endless number of possible duplicates — the problem, as ever, is finding a decent one to use as the reference or canonical question.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions :-) Almost immediately after posing the question I realized I could just return the new pointer. But somehow it seems more elegant to use the other suggestion, a pointer to a pointer, if I can just get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy fix would be to change your function to return the new list head:

```
Node * insert( struct Node * list, int value )
{
    ...
}
```

Use like this:

`myList = insert( myList, someNumber )`

---

It's hard to explain the use case you want without pictures. You want to pass a pointer to your list head pointer to `insert()`. Inside `insert()` you can then modify what that pointer-pointer points to (dereference it) to alter your list head.

Declare your function like this:

```
void insert( struct Node ** ioList, int value ) { ... }
```

Here `ioList` is of type `Node **`, which is a pointer to a pointer to a `Node`. (A rule of thumb: read types from right to left)

Call it like this:

```
struct Node * myList = /*create list here*/ ;
insert( &myList, /*some number*/ );
```

The `&` operator creates a pointer to it's argument. So we're getting a pointer to `myList`. (Which is a pointer to a `Node`)

Now we have a pointer that points to `myList`.

Inside `insert`, assign to `*ioList` to alter what `ioList` points to (`myList`):

```
// make myList point to the new list head:
*ioList = /*new list head*/
```

Comment: I realize I could solve the problem by returning the pointer, but this solution seems more elegant. I felt like I was just getting the hang of pointers, but I think I need to work a little to get my head around pointers to pointer...

Comment: In your code, where you call insert() you will be modifying the value of your list pointer... It's harder to manage and find bugs in code where this happens. I'd personally use the first option of returning the new list head.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers point to a location in memory.  Your function creates a new memory location and assigns it to a pointer that has been passed by value. I assume you are trying to add a new node to your existing linked list.

Your function doesn't operate this way unfortunately as you are assigning a new address to your linked list every time.

I like the use of sparse arrays.  If you know the max size of your list, they are easier to use than a contiguous location of memory that store structures that may have to be realloced later.

```
void insert(struct node* list[], int *currentIndex, int value)
{
    struct node * newNode;

     newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
     list[*currentIndex++] = newNode;

     ....
}
```

Comment: I am looking into linked lists as part of a programming assignment in CS50. There the reason for using linked lists seems to be that one does not need to know the size of the list beforehand. One just mallocs a new node as it is added to the list. The node in the example only holds an integer and a pointer to the next node.